# Sendmail replacement on a home debian machine

Tags: linux, debian, email, sendmail

Once in a while I'd like to report a bug using Debian `reportbug` facility... or use other programs which assume working `sendmail`. However I'd rather like not to install any mail server on a home desktop machine.

I know I can install `esmtp`, configure it... but maybe there is simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure [debian reportbug](http://build01.tow5.interdose.net/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+reportbug) to use your ISP's mail server to send outgoing mail (I have comcast and they even allow me to create an extra email address to use).

Answer (score 2):

I have all my Debian systems with the default exim4 MTA configured as a "satellite system" of my ISP's outgoing mailserver (I stay well away from sendmail after previous experiences on RedHat).  I have no problems using reportbug or anything else which expects to be able to send mail via a service on localhost.  However, it does mean things like cron logs make a roundabout trip via my ISP's POP3 mailbox rather than just being locally delivered... but it works for me.

(If you want to explore this route, during `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, the relevant option for "General type of mail configuration" is "mail sent by smarthost; no local mail" and later give the name of the ISP's SMTP server for "outgoing smarthost".)

Answer (score 1):

Jeff is right that you should be able to do this directly via reportbug (see the note in the docs about $HOME/.reportbugrc for how to set this up on your machine).

However, if you end up wanting an SMTP server for yourself anyhow, I highly recommend [ssmtp](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/ssmtp). It's an extremely easy-to-use, easy-to-configure SMTP server for a home machine. It also has no dependencies that you shouldn't already have installed, so the installation is trivial and costs you no disk space to try.

Comment: I did not know ssmtp. It seems that it is unmaintained: http://www.davidgrant.ca/ssmtp_vs_postfix_no_contest

Answer (score 0):

[Esmtp](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/) can be configured to use your ISP's mail server, I've set it up with gmail and works great.